# What causes a socket write error (135) when uploading a big file using Transmit?

Tags: linux, ftp, apache-http-server

I am trying to upload a 12MB .wav file on a Mac running Transmit to a Linux box running Apache and get the following error after uploading just 160KB of the file:

```
error-135-socket-write-error
```

Any clues why I may be getting this? I have successfully uploaded much larger files in the past and nothing has changed on the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk was full.